# Help finding a freescale MC68LK331CPV27 datasheet

Tags: datasheet, cpu, freescale

I'm looking for an old cpu datasheet which seems to have disappeared from existence.  It is for a freescale MC68LK331CPV27.

I've ran out of stock on an old cpu and the replacement (MC68LK332ACAG16) is supposed to be pin compatible but it isn't working.

I'm hoping there's a guru out there who knows where I can dig deeper in finding this item.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[MC68331 Product Summary](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=MC68331)

It comes in 132-pin PQFP and 144-pin QFP.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked thru those documents and haven't seen the part # specified however.